# Why dont have ConfigurationManager?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, using

I was trying to use ConfigurationManager, at first `System.Configuration` didnt have it and I was wondering why.

[image]

After some tries, after include the reference `System.Configuration` now it show.

[image]

So how is I can use `System.Configuration` without reference? But need the reference to use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`

[image]

Comment: What type of project is this?  What framework version are you targeting?  Are you sure your reference is spelled/cased appropriately?

Comment: It is possible to have same namespaces in multiple assemblies.

Comment: How did you add that reference? It's strange that it's `System.configuration` instead of `System.Configuration`.

Comment: The documentation explicitly states that `ConfigurationManager` is in `System.Configuration.dll` ([MSDN: ConfigurationManager Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) ). Since a namespace can be used in other assemblies, I would guess that something in the `System` assembly has something there.

Comment: @mason Well as you can see there wasnt anything `configuration` related on the References tree. I just right click and add from the framework, but even when appear on lowercase, the identity is CamelCase https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyvs9.png

Comment: @maccettura Is  a windows form project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .net1.0 and 1.1 the namespace System.Configuration was under `System.dll`.
Since .net2.0 there's a new assembly - `System.Configuration.dll`.

Back at the days we had to use [ConfigurationSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsettings(v=vs.110).aspx), which is in the `System.dll` assembly and is obsolete now.
Now, we are using [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) and its in the `System.Configuration.dll` assembly.

So, the reason you are getting `System.Configuration` is probably because you are referencing `System.dll` which is included by default in winforms applications.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the *namespace* is split across a few *assemblies*

You might have been getting the original `System.Configuration` namespace from the mscorlib.dll assembly, or a similar core dll

Answer (score 1):

Any assembly can export any namespace.

MyFoo.dll can define a type within a namespace such as `System.Configuration.VeryImportant.Type`, which means that if you reference MyFoo.dll `System.Configuration` is a valid namespace, even though the `ConfigurationManager` type is defined within the `System.Configuration.dll` assembly.

There are other assemblies included by default which may include `System.Configuation` as an exported namespace.